# SSH timeout when running importDump.php on a Bitnami Mediawiki instance on Google Cloud server

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, mediawiki, bitnami

The import seems to start out ok, showing the contents of the mediawiki in the terminal window.  At some point (often around the same point in the content), the SSH terminal freezes up.  Opera Browser returns an 'out of memory' message.

2 questions -

1. Can I just start the import and ask the server to run it regardless of the status of the terminal window on my machine (or the internet connection)?
2. If no to #1, what can I modify to prevent the terminal from timing out?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the cause of the problem is not the Google Cloud server or the network but a problem with the client browser being used. 
A good test would be to do the same operation using another browser if possible and see how it goes. If the operation is successful then it means that it is a problem with the Opera browser itself.

Also check the memory configurations on the client machine to see if it can handle the request.

There has been reports of out of memory errors in Opera:

https://forums.opera.com/topic/17877/new-version-out-of-memory-issue

Comment: Thank you.  I have also tried the operation in Chrome, and it hangs (no error message though).  The laptop I am performing the operation on has 16 GB of RAM, but I'm not certain if that is what you're referring to in terms of memory config on client machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried other browsers and issue is the same then it should not be caused by the Opera browser ‘out of memory’ error.

Have you provided your Bitnami Mediawiki deployment with the correct instance specs to handle every request?

- At the Google Cloud Platform click on Products & Services which is the 
  icon with the four bars at the top left hand corner.
- On the menu go to the Compute section and hover on ‘Compute Engine’ and 
  then click on ‘VM Instances’ to view all your instances.
- Click on your Bitnami instance to see more details.
- Go to ‘Machine type’ where you can see CPU and memory allocated for the 
  instance.

Ensure Bitnami Mediawiki instance has a good profile to handle the request.

You can also check the instance performance while you’re doing the import and see how it behaves.

As per the [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps#Using_importDump.php.2C_if_you_have_shell_access), running importDump.php can take quite a long time. For a large Wikipedia dump with millions of pages, it may take days, even on a fast server.

Comment: Thanks - I have upgraded the VM instance to 2x CPUs with 13 GB (then tried again at 52 GB) of RAM.  The importDump.php still freezes up and gives the same  "out of memory" error.  CPU utilization never goes > 10%.  Disk bytes does not go > 3.6 M read, 1 M write.  Network packets tops out at 116 incoming, 405 outgoing (at the same time in the graph display).    The size of the mediawiki is < 250 MB and has about 4,500 pages.  Seems to me that the VM specs should be able to handle this...  Any further ideas why it may be timing out?

Comment: I also modified php.ini to allow 'memory_limit= 2G'  still seeing the same result...  Is this likely a problem with Bitnami, Google Cloud or my local machine??